# Use template to create multi-page ruby on rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine-7

Is there any way to create a webpage template that I will be applying to all my webpages?
I am new to ruby on rails, I have gained enough knowledge to understand how flow works in it but can't find out the way to use the same page-template for all pages on the site.
I am using RubyMine but can work on command prompt if required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just foundout that in layout, I need to place <%= yield %> to render any webpage. Not sure if i am right.

Comment: Yes that's correct you can use layout to use sample page template and include '<%= yield %>'  page specific content

Comment: See here for things you can do: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-layouts_and_embedded_ruby ... and here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/views/layout/application.html.erb** this is a common layout in which you will found `<%= yield %>` which render all the pages in `<body>` tag. Now as per your requirement you want some common template to show on all pages.

So better to make one `partial` file..For example, `Header` and `Footer` remains same in whole site. For doing this, make one partial file called **_header.html.erb** for header part and **_footer.html.erb** for footer part. Put these files under **`app/views/layout/_your_partialfile.html.erb`**

Then render them like:

```
<%= render partial: "/layouts/header" %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render partial: "/layouts/footer" %>
```

For more info refer : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

I hope this makes you clear to understand now. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was very helpful. But having another issue now. I am trying to render a form that is created with form_for, The page is not giving any error, however i can't see the form fields (i can see heading etc.). Do i need to import anything like how we do in java if you know??

Comment: @VD007 : Can you provide me some details like where you have made form's file with what name? And also let me know where and how you render it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, rails projects have a file in `app/layouts/application.html.haml` that's applied to every single page you load. You can put navbars there, login links, etc.